# Unity3D Android internal storage folder

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, save, directory

I want to create folder in Android "root" folder, **NOT in persistentDataPath**.

When I'm trying to create file or move file from persistentDataPath to, for example: "/mnt/emmc/", it says UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/mnt/emmc/" is denied.

How can I get access to the folder?

Comment: you **CAN'T**, you can **ONLY** use Application.persistentDataPath.  it's just one of those weird things about Unity - nobody has a clue why they **ever mentioned** the other paths.

Comment: No build in /unity API for that but you can do it by making your own android plugin with java.

Comment: You cannot place a file in the root directory, period. Ultimately you would need the "Root" privileges to write in /root.

Comment: Can we create a new folder on mnt emmc and then same there?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 years old but I've had a problem with the same thing recently and when I was doing my research I found that many people had a similar problem, so just posting an answer to hopefully help someone looking for it in the future :)

[How to get android's internal memory root in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504506/how-to-get-androids-internal-memory-root-in-unity)