# How to get android's internal memory root in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have seen many similar questions, seems like a lot of people trying to figure it out, I couldn't find any answer that would help me. I am making a simple app for Android using Unity.

I want to have a folder in android internal storage root, on my pc it looks like: huaweiP30\internal storage\videos\

I don't need to write anything to that folder, I want my app to list all the mp4 videos from that folder and be able to play them using unity video player, I want the user to be able to easily add more videos to it by just dropping them into that folder. I tested it on windows and the app is completed working as expected, all I need to do now is to give it the correct path to the internal storage.
Alternatively I could have the app list all .mp4 files on the whole storage if that's easier to do.

I I tried all the answers that I was able to find online, some of which worked for other people. Nothing has worked for me so far.

used this for testing on windows and works exactly how I want it. I just don't know what should I replace the path with to make it read from internal storage\videos\

```
string videosPath = "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\";

string [] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(videosPath,"*.mp4");
```

Please help me either solve it or find an alternative resolution, I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1482655/is-it-possible-to-load-video-from-android-path.html

Comment: @BooNonMooN you mean an URL like "file://videos/" would lead to videos folder in internal storage root? Will try  it in the evening soon as I'm home.

Comment: @BooNonMooN I tried that and I tried application.persistentDataPath which returns /storage/emulated/0/Android/data.... but that didnt help. when I used /storage/emulated/0/videos it didn't read the videos that I have there. I think android makes internal storage private for my app. but all the apps can access the videos on my phone so it has to be possible

Answer (score 2):

This was easier than I thought! I was researching for so long and already going crazy when all I had to do is - in my phone settings I went to permissions, memory and allowed my app to access the memory.
Then it's as simple as

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath.Substring(0, Application.persistentDataPath.IndexOf("Android", StringComparison.Ordinal));
        videosPath = path +"/videos/";
```

to get the path. without the last bit I was able to read every single video on my internal storage when I added

```
SearchOption.AllDirectories
```

here is how to make your app ask for permissions so you don't have to manually allow it. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html

The sample code is about microphone but all you need to do is just change it to ExternalStorageRead/Write, don't worry about 'External', it works for internal memory too.

Comment: Thx for letting us know. Glad you fixed it.